# Syntax Error when executing OLEDB Select statement

Tags: c#, ado.net, oledb, parameterized-query

When I run this query I get the following error:

> Syntax error(missing operator) in query expression '[Customer] = 'O'SMILE' and [Product] = 'Casserole(20kg)

Code:

```
// When print button is executed database operations        

// Load data from database based upon select query
String codeQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM [sheet1$] WHERE [Customer] = '" + lblcustomername.Text + "' and [Product]='" + lblproductname.Text + "'";

OleDbConnection Connection;
Connection = new OleDbConnection(OutputDatabaseConnectionString);

OleDbCommand Command = new OleDbCommand(codeQuery, Connection);
Command.Connection = Connection;

try
{
    Connection.Open();
    count = (Int32)Command.ExecuteScalar();
    Connection.Close();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
}
```

Comment: please consider accepting answers. It will encourage people to help you in future.

Answer (score 2):

The error is  because of the unquoted single quote "'" in the name `O'SMILE` and your use of string concatenation, rather than using a parameterised query. It also indicates that you are vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

**You must use Parameters!**

```
string sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM [sheet1$] WHERE [Customer] = @customer and [Product] = @product";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(/* connection info */))
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("customer", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = lblcustomername.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("product", SqlDbType.VarChar, 120).Value = lblproductname.Text;

    count = (Int32)command.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Comment: Hi there, I sill get the error 'Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression ''O'SMILE','Bones','0','